# Postgres reported table / db size varies wildly from dump size

Tags: postgresql, database-size

I have a very strange misreporting of the size of one specific database.

According to `\l+` in `psql` the DB size is 292 MB.

Doing a sum over the sizes reported by the following statement also reports very close to 292 MB.

```
SELECT
    table_name,
    pg_size_pretty(total_size) AS total_size
FROM (
    SELECT
        table_name,
        pg_total_relation_size(table_name) AS total_size
    FROM (
        SELECT ('"' || table_schema || '"."' || table_name || '"') AS table_name
        FROM information_schema.tables
    ) AS all_tables
    ORDER BY total_size DESC
) AS pretty_sizes
```

Yet a `pg_dump` of this database produces a sql file of 2.02 GB

I suspect that both counting methods skip LOBs since there are two tables in this database that contain `TEXT` fields with largish content (up to ~4MB per row).

Is there a way to include LOBs in the size calculation?

**EDIT:**
It gets even stranger:

This query:

```
SELECT SUM(LENGTH(text_column))
FROM some_table
```

Gives a result of 2,091,245,318 (i.e. 2.02 GiB) which is about the size of the dump.

Comment: Your question related to LOBs is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636850/does-pg-database-size-include-blobs-in-pg-largeobject

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the answer (see my edit above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that unless your application is going out of its way to use the [large objects](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/largeobjects.html) interface, then it is not storing those columns as LOBs. Normal columns can store up to 1gb using [TOAST](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-toast.html) (The Oversized-Attribute Storage Technique).

In addition to storing the data out of line, it may be stored compressed. Although you don't say so I assume the dump you are composing with is uncompressed, which could account for most of the size difference.

Comment: Hm, compression might explain it. Is there a way to query if rows are stored compressed?

Comment: @UloPe Not directly. However TEXT and other (VAR)CHAR types have a default storage strategy of 'EXTENDED' which means they definitely will be compressed if > TOAST_TUPLE_THRESHOLD (2kb). Read the page I linked about TOAST.

Comment: Your edit seems to validate my hypothesis. What size is your dump if you compress it using eg. gzip?

Comment: Indeed. Compressing the dump file with gzip reduces it's size to about 150 MB. Still I think it would be nice if there was a way to get the "real" size a databases content.

Answer (score -1):

a sql file will always be much bigger than the data stored in your db. It's a text representation of binary data.

Comment: I'm aware of that. However in this case we're talking about an order of magnitude in size difference in a database where the prevalent data type is text - see my edit in the original question.

Comment: I think large objects are compressed in postgresql, which would explain why the text format is that bigger...

Comment: This is definitely not true.  It very much depends on the data.  I've done a short test on one of my toy databases, it reports 8554 kB in `psql`, the text format dump is 2279 kB.